# xslt prepend child tag

Tags: xslt

I'm stuck on this one.
Can't figure out how to prepend an child element and keep the attributes of the enclosing element.

I Have

```
<GXXML>
    <FEATURECLASS ProgID="mmGeoDatabase.MMFeatureClass.1">
        <SUBTYPE ProgID="mmGeoDatabase.MMSubType.1">
            <FIELD ProgID="mmGeoDatabase.MMField.1">
                <AUTOVALUE ProgID="mmGeoDatabase.MMAutoValue.1" EDITEVENT="mmEventFeatureCreate" EDITORTYPE="0">
                    <AVDISPLAYORDER>0</AVDISPLAYORDER>
                    <AVEDMTABLESUBTYPE>888888</AVEDMTABLESUBTYPE>
                    <AVEDMPROPERTYTYPE>888888</AVEDMPROPERTYTYPE>
                </AUTOVALUE>
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD ProgID="mmGeoDatabase.MMField.1">
                <AUTOVALUE ProgID="mmGeoDatabase.MMAutoValue.1" EDITEVENT="mmEventFeatureCreate" EDITORTYPE="0">
                    <AVDISPLAYORDER>0</AVDISPLAYORDER>
                    <AVEDMTABLESUBTYPE>888888</AVEDMTABLESUBTYPE>
                    <AVEDMPROPERTYTYPE>888888</AVEDMPROPERTYTYPE>
                </AUTOVALUE>
            </FIELD>
        </SUBTYPE>
    </FEATURECLASS>
</GXXML>
```

And I want this

```
<GXXML>
    <FEATURECLASS ProgID="mmGeoDatabase.MMFeatureClass.1">
        <SUBTYPE ProgID="mmGeoDatabase.MMSubType.1">
            <FIELD ProgID="mmGeoDatabase.MMField.1">
                <AUTOVALUE ProgID="mmGeoDatabase.MMAutoValue.1" EDITEVENT="mmEventFeatureCreate" EDITORTYPE="0">
                    <AUTOGENID>{DE2DCE92-8CCF-42DB-B9F9-89D1DE5EDE6A}</AUTOGENID>
                    <AUTOVALUENAME>ESRI Field Rules</AUTOVALUENAME>
                    <AVDISPLAYORDER>0</AVDISPLAYORDER>
                    <AVEDMTABLESUBTYPE>888888</AVEDMTABLESUBTYPE>
                    <AVEDMPROPERTYTYPE>888888</AVEDMPROPERTYTYPE>
                </AUTOVALUE>
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD ProgID="mmGeoDatabase.MMField.1">
                <AUTOVALUE ProgID="mmGeoDatabase.MMAutoValue.1" EDITEVENT="mmEventFeatureCreate" EDITORTYPE="0">
                    <AUTOGENID>{DE2DCE92-8CCF-42DB-B9F9-89D1DE5EDE6A}</AUTOGENID>
                    <AUTOVALUENAME>ESRI Field Rules</AUTOVALUENAME>
                    <AVDISPLAYORDER>0</AVDISPLAYORDER>
                    <AVEDMTABLESUBTYPE>888888</AVEDMTABLESUBTYPE>
                    <AVEDMPROPERTYTYPE>888888</AVEDMPROPERTYTYPE>
                </AUTOVALUE>
            </FIELD>
        </SUBTYPE>
    </FEATURECLASS>
</GXXML>
```

This Xpath choses elements where I want to insert "missing" child elements

```
GXXML/FEATURECLASS/SUBTYPE//FIELD/AUTOVALUE[@EDITEVENT='mmEventFeatureCreate'][not(AUTOGENID)]
```

When I run my xslt I either loses attributes, but child element is in the right order
or the chile element i not in the right order (dtd does not validate) but the enclosing tag keeps the attributes.

An xslt that shows this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="GXXML/FEATURECLASS/SUBTYPE/FIELD[1]/AUTOVALUE[@EDITEVENT='mmEventFeatureCreate'][not(AUTOGENID)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            <AUTOGENID>{DE2DCE92-8CCF-42DB-B9F9-89D1DE5EDE6A}</AUTOGENID>
            <AUTOVALUENAME>ESRI Field Rules</AUTOVALUENAME>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="GXXML/FEATURECLASS/SUBTYPE/FIELD[2]/AUTOVALUE[@EDITEVENT='mmEventFeatureCreate'][not(AUTOGENID)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <AUTOGENID>{DE2DCE92-8CCF-42DB-B9F9-89D1DE5EDE6A}</AUTOGENID>
            <AUTOVALUENAME>ESRI Field Rules</AUTOVALUENAME>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I get from my xslt:

```
<GXXML>
    <FEATURECLASS ProgID="mmGeoDatabase.MMFeatureClass.1">
        <SUBTYPE ProgID="mmGeoDatabase.MMSubType.1">
            <FIELD ProgID="mmGeoDatabase.MMField.1">
                <AUTOVALUE ProgID="mmGeoDatabase.MMAutoValue.1" EDITEVENT="mmEventFeatureCreate" EDITORTYPE="0">
                    <AVDISPLAYORDER>0</AVDISPLAYORDER>
                    <AVEDMTABLESUBTYPE>888888</AVEDMTABLESUBTYPE>
                    <AVEDMPROPERTYTYPE>888888</AVEDMPROPERTYTYPE>
                    <AUTOGENID>{DE2DCE92-8CCF-42DB-B9F9-89D1DE5EDE6A}</AUTOGENID>
                    <AUTOVALUENAME>ESRI Field Rules</AUTOVALUENAME>
                </AUTOVALUE>
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD ProgID="mmGeoDatabase.MMField.1">
                <AUTOVALUE>
                    <AUTOGENID>{DE2DCE92-8CCF-42DB-B9F9-89D1DE5EDE6A}</AUTOGENID>
                    <AUTOVALUENAME>ESRI Field Rules</AUTOVALUENAME>
                    <AVDISPLAYORDER>0</AVDISPLAYORDER>
                    <AVEDMTABLESUBTYPE>888888</AVEDMTABLESUBTYPE>
                    <AVEDMPROPERTYTYPE>888888</AVEDMPROPERTYTYPE>
                </AUTOVALUE>
            </FIELD>
        </SUBTYPE>
    </FEATURECLASS>
</GXXML>
```

Edit after Tim C's answer:
This is the xslt that gives the desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="GXXML/FEATURECLASS/SUBTYPE//FIELD/AUTOVALUE[@EDITEVENT='mmEventFeatureCreate'][not(AUTOGENID)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <AUTOGENID>{DE2DCE92-8CCF-42DB-B9F9-89D1DE5EDE6A}</AUTOGENID>
            <AUTOVALUENAME>ESRI Field Rules</AUTOVALUENAME>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is replace this....

```
<xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   <AUTOGENID>{DE2DCE92-8CCF-42DB-B9F9-89D1DE5EDE6A}</AUTOGENID>
   <AUTOVALUENAME>ESRI Field Rules</AUTOVALUENAME>
</xsl:copy>
```

With this...

```
<xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
   <AUTOGENID>{DE2DCE92-8CCF-42DB-B9F9-89D1DE5EDE6A}</AUTOGENID>
   <AUTOVALUENAME>ESRI Field Rules</AUTOVALUENAME>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
```

So, you copy the attributes first, then add your new nodes, and then copy the other existing nodes..